# conditions for stronger measurability

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am curious about the following question:

If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a real valued function, what condition(s) should be imposed on $f$ so that for any set $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ which is Lebesgue measurable, $f^{-1}(A)$ is also Lebesgue measurable?

Can any one give some general results (or hints for that) or show some concrete example(s)? I think only continuity (or even uniform continuity) is not enough.